# Resizing Columns of a TableView in javaFX

Tags: javafx

How can i resize the width of a column according to the length of the data it occupies.
The table has got about 15 columns and i want to show the column heading without resizing it manually. Is there any option for autoresize?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TableView.setColumnResizePolicy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setColumnResizePolicy-javafx.util.Callback-) is what you are looking for.

For Example:

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```